# UWP/WinRT: Is it possible to change a Style using an AdaptiveTrigger?

Tags: responsive-design, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm trying to make it so that when the window drops below a certain size, the buttons shrink in size.

Here is the code for my Style:

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="68"/>
</Style>
```

How can I cause all `AppBarButtons` to become 64 width when the window drops below 720 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've discussed this in your another question, your `AppBarSeparators` are generated in the Pivot's DataTemplate.

Still you can use DataBinding with Converter to do this, and if the size of the window is changeable during the run-time, you may also need complete your data source class with `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.

For example here:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:WidthConverter x:Key="cvt" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot x:Name="docPivot" ItemsSource="{x:Bind pivotlist}" SizeChanged="docPivot_SizeChanged">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                        <AppBarButton Background="Red" Icon="Accept" Label="Accept" Width="{Binding WindowWidth, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

The other things are the same as my answer in your last question. And the `WidthConverter` here is like this:

```cs
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        double? width = (double?)value;
        if (width <= 720)
            return 64;
        return 68;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it's necessary to handle the width individually for each item that uses a style, and it's not possible to change the style directly to change all items that use it together in a much cleaner way?

Comment: @WilliamJones, I couldn't think any clean way here to manage this. Maybe there is other easier way, but it should anyway be done in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy enough, not sure if you can set styles generally, or if you are restricted to named elements though, so I would create a visualstatemanager that does that first, and then explore my options further:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="Button1.Width" Value="100" />                        
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="Button1.Width" Value="68" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```